# Do not Save Ip Address in ISP

Tags: security, internet, connection

I want Use a way to do not Save My Ip Address in ISp.I want Use a Secure Connection with No Spy.

Edit: Hide IP Software Can Help me?

Last Edit:
    ***VPN Connection Can Help me?
    Web Based Proxy Can Help me?
    Hide Ip Tools Can Help me?
    Which Tools?***

Please Help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't bypass your ISP. Who would need an ISP if you could bypass them?

Buuut...you could use either a encrypted/secured connection (VPN) or an proxy, the later will only help to prevent the owners of the servers to directly see you.

**Edit:** Using an encrypted VPN connection will only prevent analyses of the traffic, your ISP of course will still know that you were online. It's his job to know that.

Comment: the ISP will still have your local IP address on record.

Comment: @Molly: Of course, added it.

Answer (score 3):

In most countries ISPs are obliged by law to keep their customers' IP records, nothing you can do about.

If you want anonymity, get a prepaid 3G modem ... and don't pay with a credit card. :)

Answer (score 3):

It won't work at the ISP level, but you might want to check out http://www.torproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free web based proxy service. These are very easy to use and will anonymize all your web traffic. The proxy works by making the web request for you (from the proxy server), then delivering the web response (html page, images, etc..) back to you.

http://www.hidemyass.com

If you want to mask your traffic at an 'isp' level, you need to use the service over a secure connection (https). HTTPS is HTTP over SSL, so the entire transaction is encrypted.

Other proxy solutions include using a SOCKS/HTTP proxy. You can set your browser to use one of these proxies in the browser settings. Since the proxy tunnel is managed by the browser, its usage is transparent and work better.

Comment: a web based proxy service doesn't mask your IP address from your internet service provider.